# How to add fields for java.util.map in data object of jboss rhpam bpmn

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn, business-process-management, redhat-bpm

I am using jboss rhpam for bpmn in that I have created the data object, I want to use one field with data type as `jav.util.map` but I in that data object this type is not present. So Can we add Map in the data object. And if added how the form will be generated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Source

   [image]
2. now you can type whatever you want, you will get the source code of the class in JAVA

Comment: Hi @Bashir . I have one question regarding this tool. I have created the flow in that tool. And on other day while starting this tool I have clicked on init.sh file. Due to this tool installed again. And my whole work is lost. Now I dont have anything in that. So do you have any information how to recover the deleted spaces and projects in this tool

Comment: sorry, but as I know you cannot recover the files .. :/

Comment: Okay @Bashir. In RHPAM there is Task Inbox. In that we need to approve the task. Instead of Task Inbox can I use this in my existing angular UI. Based on login it will show the pending tasks of respective manager and then approve it.

Comment: Basically I am looking for way to add a approval flow in my existing angular application. I want to use PAM to create a workflow only. And all approval process should happen from angular UI of my application. So Is it possible using rhpam or there is another way to do this